# Google Maps push() marker into marker array does not increment the array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load a basic map with couple of markers based on the GeoJSON location data that I am feeding. Am able to get the map and the marker up and running. My intention is to have the map constant and redraw the marker and the circle object over the duration I am mentioning in the `setInterval` duration.

The problem is am not able the re-draw the markers. I have tried erasing the markers using `setMap(NULL)`, so the map loads every time drawing the marker over and over again.

Debugging showed the `gmarkers()` length defined in the array doesn't increment even if the marker push is done into the array.

Including the code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    html {
      height: 100%
    }
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
    }
    #map-canvas {
      height: 100%
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,visualization&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="csv2geojson.js"></script>
  <script>
    var map;
     // Set a blank infoWindow to be used for each to state on click
    var infoWindow;

    var circle;
    var marker;
    var callback_results;
    var gmarkers = [];

    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.00, -98),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
        }
      }

      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
      map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ""
      });

      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/b3d22cade31083355464/raw/e1c9183c1b2e3eb068cd482281e85d82f68b9cfb/ari.json';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

     // Loop through the results array and place a circle for each
     // set of coordinates.
    window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {

      callback_results = results;
      map.data.addGeoJson(results);
      draw();

    }

    function draw() {
      //var heatmapData = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < callback_results.features.length; i++) {
        var score = callback_results.features[i].properties.COLI;
        var coords = callback_results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0]);

        //heatmapData.push(latLng);

        /*
            var weightedLoc = {
 location: latLng,
 weight: Math.pow(2, magnitude)
 };
 heatmapData.push(weightedLoc);
          */

        var circleopts = {
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          center: latLng,
          radius: 100000
        };
        circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleopts);

        var markeropts = {
          position: latLng,
          map: map
        };


        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          map: map
        });
        //console.log(marker);
        gmarkers.push(marker);


        /*
           var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: heatmapData,
        dissipating: false,
        map: map
        });
         */

      }

      // Adds an info window on click with in a state that includes the state name and COLI
      map.data.addListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        infoWindow.setContent('<div style="line-height:1.00;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">' +
          e.feature.getProperty('NAME') + '<br> COLI: ' +
          e.feature.getProperty('COLI') + '</div>');

        var anchor = new google.maps.MVCObject();
        anchor.set("position", e.latLng);
        infoWindow.open(map, anchor);
      });


    }

     // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
    function setMapOnAll(map) {
      //console.log("WTF is happening");
      for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        console.log("WTF is happening");
        gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
      }
    }

     // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
    function clearMarkers() {

      setMapOnAll(null);
    }

     // Shows any markers currently in the array.
    function showMarkers() {
      setMapOnAll(map);
    }

     // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
    function deleteMarkers() {
      clearMarkers();
      gmarkers = [];
    }


    clearMarkers();
    /*
       for (i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
       marker.setVisible(false);
       markerArray[i].setMap(null);
       }       */
     //setInterval(clearOverlays, 3000);
     //setInterval(deleteOverlays, 4000);
    setInterval(draw, 5000);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Geo Json co-ordinates used in the backend.

```
eqfeed_callback({"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{
"type":"Feature",
"properties":{"GEO_ID":"0400000US04","STATE":"04","NAME":"Arizona","LSAD":"","CENSUSAREA":113594.084,"ABVR":"AZ","COLI":103.94696969696945},
"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-112.538593,37.000674]}},
{
"type":"Feature",
"properties":{"GEO_ID":"0400000US05","STATE":"05","NAME":"Arkansas","LSAD":"","CENSUSAREA":52035.477,"ABVR":"AR","COLI":93.15411931818184},
"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-94.042964,33.019219]}}
]})
```

Comment: I had the geo JSON co-ordinates stored locally, file:///C:/Users/ivasanthp/Desktop/ari.json,  can you load the info from the snippet I stored at the end of html code?

Comment: Please create http://jsfiddle.net or similar.

Comment: Adding the jsfiddle link, for some reasons I am not able run this in the site, but am able to run it in my machine, https://jsfiddle.net/p7ztm8hh/3/

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p7ztm8hh/5/. What is not working? `console.log(gmarkers.length);` increments fine.

Comment: But I just cannot access it from the setMapOnAll() function which clears the markers which I am invoking from the clearMarkers() function. Since it is not clearing the marker, the recursive function redraws the marker over it repeatedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding / removing markers works just fine, but you have additional layer set here:

```
map.data.addGeoJson(results);
```

Comment it out and adding / removing markers works.

Looks like one of these methods to add markers is redundant, choose which one :)

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p7ztm8hh/6/